# Unwanted behaivour with iframes and transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a bit of a tricky one here. Please keep in mind I am very new to web dev. I am trying to get videos to open with a fade in and a slide when a text is clicked. I am using iframes as it allows me to avoid jquery's slide function which is not smooth enough unless it's cached. I have never used iframes before and I am running into unwanted behaivour. When I click on a link, ALL VIDEOS, open up. See gif:

[image]

here is my code. I have edited the text out for clarity.

The way I've gone about it is that all videos have a class that has them collapsed and with the javascript I add a class of "open". But as I said, it seems to target all of them. Any help appreciated. P

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body> 
<div id="wrap">

<p id="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor...
    <span id="link1">link 1</span> 
    <span id="wrap1">
        <iframe  id="frame" class="rect" src="iframe.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
    </span>
....Lorem ipsum dolor...
    <span id="link2">link 2</span>
    <span id="wrap2">
        <iframe  id="frame2" class="rect" src="iframe2.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
    </span>
 ....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</p>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap{
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 350px;
}

p{
    line-height: 2em;
}

iframe {
    border:0 none;
}

.rect{
    float: left;
    height: 0px;
    width: 350px;

    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    opacity: 0;

    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.open {
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#link1{
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

#link2{
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#link1").click(function(){


        if ($( ".rect" ).hasClass( "open" )){

            $(".rect").removeClass("open");

            $("body").find("iframe").contents().find("#pasc").get(0).pause();

        } else {

        $(".rect").addClass("open");

       $("body").find("iframe").contents().find("#vid1").get(0).play();
        }
    });

    $("#link2").click(function(){


        if ($( ".rect" ).hasClass( "open" )){

            $(".rect").removeClass("open");

            $("body").find("iframe").contents().find("#vid2").get(0).pause();


        } else {

        $(".rect").addClass("open");

         $("body").find("iframe").contents().find("#vid2").get(0).play();
        }  
    });
    });
```

**iframe1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">       
</head>
<body>
    <video id="vid1" width="350" height="200" >
        <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">       
</head>
<body>
    <video id="vid2" width="350" height="200" >
        <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When clicking a link you're targeting all the iframes. Change `$("body").find("iframe")` to `$(this).next("iframe")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/214/)**.

When you use `$(".rect")` it'll target all the elements with class `rect`, same thing when you call `$("body").find("iframe")` it will target all the iframes in the page and that you're problem here.

so to avoid that you could use the current object `$(this)` to refer to the related `iframe` with the clicked `link` using :

```
$(this).next().find('.rect');
```

So you could store it in a variable and just use it to trigger all the other functions :

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
    var rect = $(this).next().find('.rect');

    if (rect.hasClass( "open" ))
    {
        rect.removeClass("open");
        rect.contents().find("#pasc").get(0).pause();
    } else {
        rect.addClass("open");
        rect.contents().find("#vid1").get(0).play();
    }
});

$("#link2").click(function(){
    var rect = $(this).next().find('.rect');

    if (rect.hasClass( "open" ))
    {
        rect.removeClass("open");
        rect.contents().find("#vid2").get(0).pause();
    } else {
        rect.addClass("open");
        rect.contents().find("#vid2").get(0).play();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. this helps. would you happen to know if there's a way to not have to use two iframe files... can i have both videos on one? tx

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
$(".rect").addClass("open");
```

you are adding the `open` class to ALL elements who have the `.rect` class.

You need to use the iframe id instead so you can target only a specific iframe, like:

```
$("#frame2").addClass("open");
```